# PL/SQL assistance to convert each student’s overall score to a letter grade

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a PL/SQL block that converts each student’s overall score to a letter grade by the rule 90-100=A, 80-89.99=B, 65-79.99=C, 0-64.99=F, and include the letter grade in the output. I am trying to figure out how exactly to insert an IF or CASE statement into the existing code. The output should look like the following:

```
445 Seinfeld 92.1 A
909 Costanza 78.2 C
```

Code:

```
DROP TABLE STUDENT CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
    ID      CHAR(3),
    Name        VARCHAR2(20),
    Midterm NUMBER(3,0)     CHECK (Midterm>=0 AND Midterm<=100),
    Final       NUMBER(3,0) CHECK (Final>=0 AND Final<=100),
    Homework    NUMBER(3,0) CHECK (Homework>=0 AND Homework<=100),

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ( '445', 'Seinfeld', 85, 90, 99 );
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ( '909', 'Costanza', 74, 72, 86 );
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ( '123', 'Benes', 93, 89, 91 );
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ( '111', 'Kramer', 99, 91, 93 );
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ( '667', 'Newman', 78, 82, 83 );
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ( '888', 'Banya', 50, 65, 50 );
SELECT * FROM STUDENT;

DROP TABLE WEIGHTS CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE WEIGHTS
(
    MidPct  NUMBER(2,0) CHECK (MidPct>=0 AND MidPct<=100),
    FinPct  NUMBER(2,0) CHECK (FinPct>=0 AND FinPct<=100),
    HWPct       NUMBER(2,0) CHECK (HWPct>=0 AND HWPct<=100)
);
INSERT INTO WEIGHTS VALUES ( 30, 30, 40 );
SELECT * FROM WEIGHTS;

declare
 Midpct WEIGHTS.midpct%type;
 Finpct WEIGHTS.finpct%type;
 Hwpct WEIGHTS.hwpct%type;

 studentName student.name%type;
 studentID student.id%type;
 Midterm student.midterm%type;
 Final student.final%type;
 Homework student.homework%type;
 average number(5,2);

 cursor studentPtr is SELECT * FROM STUDENT;

begin

  open studentPtr;

  loop

    fetch studentPtr into studentID, studentName, Midterm, Final, Homework;
    average:=(Midterm + Final + Homework)/3;

    if studentPtr%found then

               <<<<<<CALCULATE LETTER GRADE HERE, I THINK????>>>>>>>

          dbms_output.put_line(studentID  ||' '|| studentName|| ' '||average||' ');

    else`enter code here`

    exit;

        end if;

    end loop;

    close studentPtr;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the PL/SQL, but why not just do it in the cursor statement?

```
 cursor studentPtr is
     SELECT s.*,
            (case when score >= 90 then 'A'
                  when score >= 80 then 'B'
                  when score >= 65 then 'C'
                  else 'F'
             end) as LetterGrade
     FROM STUDENT s;
```

Then you can access it through the cursor.

EDIT:

You want to put the average into the query:

```
 cursor studentPtr is
     SELECT s.*,
            (case when (midterm + final + homework) / 3 >= 90 then 'A'
                  when (midterm + final + homework) / 3 >= 80 then 'B'
                  when (midterm + final + homework) / 3 >= 65 then 'C'
                  else 'F'
             end) as LetterGrade
     FROM STUDENT s;
```

Comment: He just needs to calculate his average score and replace score in your example with (midterm +  final + homework)/3.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in a single query, as follows:

```
SELECT q.*, 
       CASE 
         WHEN q.WEIGHTED_SCORE >= 90 THEN 'A'
         WHEN q.WEIGHTED_SCORE >= 80 THEN 'B'
         WHEN q.WEIGHTED_SCORE >= 65 THEN 'C'
         ELSE 'F'
       END AS GRADE
  FROM (SELECT s.ID,
               s.NAME,
              (s.MIDTERM    * (w.MIDPCT/100)) +
                (s.FINAL    * (w.FINPCT/100)) +
                (s.HOMEWORK * (w.HWPCT/100)) AS WEIGHTED_SCORE
  FROM STUDENT s
  CROSS JOIN WEIGHTS w) q;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39a94/6).

Then all you have to do is add a loop on this query and print the results as you want them.

Share and enjoy.